# How can I make the UIWebView scroll faster?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I Have a UIWebView with a long html content and I wish to give the user the ability to quickly scroll to sections of the html.

Could this be done?

I wish to make the scrolling more sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [anchor element](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).
You can change the [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) of the page (either with javascript or with obj-c)in order to scroll to a certain anchor.

Comment: What you are suggesting is to open the html at a specific place(anchor) but i wish to give the user the ability to scroll faster to sections that he wishes but not to a specific place.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebView contains a UIScrollView that handles the scrolling. I have seen code to get it by getting the first subview. Since iOS 5 there is a property to get it's scrollView.

When you have the scrollView you can do everything with it like setting the contentOffset or animate it manually.

Comment: I didn't understand how to set the scrolling sensitivity of the UIScrollView